Proving the number of vertices of a K-regular graphs
The question is "Show that every regular graph with an odd degree has an even number of vertices", from Basic Graph theory by Rahman.
as my proof, is it enough to say that, "given an odd k-graph denoted by A, its vertex a in A will be connected to k other vertices. So, A+1 is even since A is odd." Although i understand the concept of the hand-shaking lemma, I don't know how to incorporate it to the proof.

Prove the statement for the more general class of graphs. $\quad$ Your proof makes no sense to me. Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "Graph A is odd"? How is a graph a number?

The $k$-regular graph has degree $k$ for each vertex. Call the number of vertices $v$. Then we have that the total edges is found by multiplying $k$ and $v$, except each edge is therefore double counted (if it connects $v_1$ and $v_2$, then we have counted it as both $v_1 v_2$ and $v_2 v_1$) which is, presumably, what you mean by the handshaking lemma.
Therefore, the total number of edges is $vk/2$, which we know is a counting number (since it counts a physical, discrete object: edges). We also know that $k$ is odd, which means that $k$ is not a multiple of $2$. So, how can we get $vk/2$ to be a counting number?
This occurs if, and only if, $v$ or $k$ is even (so that the $2$'s can cancel). We have seen that $k$ is not divisible by $2$, so it must be that $v$ is divisible by $2$. In other words, $v$ is even as desired.

Your attempt at a proof doesn't make much sense: not all vertices in $A$ are necessarily adjacent to $a$.
Here's an outline for an argument using the handshaking lemma: the lemma tells you that twice the number of edges in a graph equals the sum of the degrees, especially, it tells you that the sum of the degrees in any graph is even. Now a sum of odd numbers is even iff the sum has an even number of summands.
